# Azure APIM json-to xml gives xml with BOM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am having an issue with an Azure integration scenario where we are receiving a JSON message on Azure APIM from Azure datafactory and we are sending this using APIM in XML format to an external REST receiver a BOM is added. Question is how to remove this. Is there an APIM policy available for it?

Azure Datafactory
Pick up a XML file and we transmit it using copy to Azure APIM

[image: DataFactory Pipeline]

[image]

[image]

[image: JSON source]

Result (captured with requestbin)

[image: XML output]

APIM policy used to transform to XML

`<json-to-xml apply="always" consider-accept-header="false" parse-date="false" namespace-separator=":" />`

Comment: mostly, it may be that the BOM is present already in the JSON that was received by APIM.  check your source. Because, there is no property or way in API M transform policies that can control this byte order mark, see APIM transform [policy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#ConvertJSONtoXML)

Comment: This might be because of encodig and/or headers. Do you have more information about the JSON endpoint or response? Also: goedemorgen 

Comment: added some additional details. to be complete. we pickup a XML file from a sFTP server using DataFactory we forward this to our APIM on Azure and we forward this to the external party.